# How to create external client for cooja?

Tags: contiki

I designed an authentication protocol for IoT. Now I want to emulate my protocol with the Cooja simulator, in order to test power consumption.

My scheme is gateway-based, so I used the RPL-Border-Router sample as gateway. and some motes as sensors. I used the Tunslip tool to connect my network to internet.

Now I want to implement my client, so that it communicate to my RPL network in order to key agreement.

As I searched I found that the client should be on a Firefox plugin Copper. (Is there any other way to implement client? if yes, what is that?)

As I told before in my own protocol, there is key agreement phase between client and Cooja motes. But I have problem to handle this  phase in Copper. It seems that the requests and responses from client (Copper) send as a packet (with get, post,..) to Cooja motes. So how to implement packets in copper?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Copper](https://github.com/mkovatsc/Copper) actually is a tool for sending CoAP requests; it is a simpler implementation of REST service. If you want to work with another protocol (not HTTP) then you should look for another tool.